# z-index on an element set to 9 in css but appearing as 0 in Chrome Inspector > "Computed" value

Tags: css, z-index

I'm trying to get some elements to overlap each other in a particular order. It should be from top to bottom:

- text in a "footer" element with id of "credit"
- "a" element with id of "kepler", containing a cat image
- background image, whose parent has an id of "slide-3"

I have the following HTML

```
        <div class="slide" id="slide-3">
            <img src="https://mrengy.github.io/card2016/img/silhouettes.jpg" alt="silhouettes against wall with pattern" class="full-img" />
            <footer id="credit" class="main wrapper clearfix">
                <h2>
                    <a href="http://anilaagha.com/intersections/">Intersections, 2013</a>
                </h2>
                <p>by Anila Quayyum Agha</p>
                <p>Displayed at the Peabody Essex Museum</p>
            </footer>
            <a href="http://placekitten.com/" id="kepler">
                <img src="https://mrengy.github.io/card2016/img/kepler.png" alt="our cat, Kepler"/>
            </a>
        </div>
```

And the following CSS

```
html {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.slide {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
}

.full-img{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.main-container{
    text-align:left;
}

#slide-1, #credit{
    z-index:9;
}
#slide-3{
    z-index:6;
    background:#AD6E1A;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#slide-4{
    z-index:7;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#kepler{
    display:block;
    z-index:8;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-20px;
    right:10%;
}

#credit{
    text-align:left;
}
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/mrengy/pen/QGNbBZ

But in Chrome, you can see if you make the browser window narrow enough, the cat will overlap the text in the "footer" element.

When I use the Chrome inspector on the "footer" element, it [shows a z-index of 9](http://screencast.com/t/S9W6Tqi2). However, when I click the "Computed" tab, it [shows a z-index of 0](http://screencast.com/t/nQ5RxAlMz). Not sure what that means.

How can I get the text in the "footer" element to layer on top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that elements without position are static by default, and static positioned elements don't have z-index values.

If you set the position of the `footer` to `relative`, the `z-index` will take effect:

```
#credit {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is the update on your example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWedLV

Answer (score 1):

you will need to add media query and then add z-index for the screen size in which you are checking.

for example. if in chrome you are  checking this at screen size 320x480, then add media query for this screen size and add z-index in that block.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) {
#slide-1, #credit{
    z-index:9;
}
}
```